# Não consigo atualizar jFrame apartir de uma Thread java

Tags: java, swing, thread

Tenho um codigo que faz a leitura da Porta serial atravez de uma thread, mais quando tento atualizar uma label eu não consigo. Implementei uma classe SerialRead Runnable, e nessa classe eu executo um loop para ler a porta serial. Até ai tudo bem, consigo ler a porta serial e imprimir ela no console. Mais quando eu tento atualizar a Label jLtempoatual, nada acontece na interface grafica. Ja testei se esta rodando em EDT e esta rodando tudo em EDT. Porem a jLtempoatual não esta atualizando em tempo de execução no jFrame.

```
import gnu.io.CommPort;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
/**
 *
 * @author bruno
 */
public class Controle extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Controle
     */
    public Controle() {

        initComponents();


    }
    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          


    private void jLtempatualMouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       

    }                                      

       public void Transporte(final String comando) {  


jLtempatual.setText(comando);

    } 




     public  void connect ( String portName ) throws Exception
    {
        CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName); // portName é o nome da porta que vai ser aberta para comunicação
        if ( portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned() )
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Porta está atualmente em uso");
        }
        else
        {
            CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(),2000);

            if ( commPort instanceof SerialPort )
            {
                SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
                serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE); //Parametros de comunicação, o primeiro numero é a velocidade de comunicação.

                InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
                //OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();


                  Thread Leitura = new Thread(new SerialReader(in), "Leitura thread");  
        Leitura.setDaemon(true);  
        Leitura.start(); 


               // (new Thread(new SerialWriter(out))).start();

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Somente as portas seriais são suportadas.");
            }
        }     
    }

public class  SerialReader implements Runnable 
    {
        InputStream in;
        String teste;
        public  SerialReader ( InputStream in )
        {
            this.in = in;
        }


        //EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run ()
        {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len = -1;

            try
            {
                while ( ( len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1 ) //Ler a serial e coloca na variavel buffer
                {
                    teste=new String(buffer,0,len);
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {  
                        public void run() {  
                    System.out.print(teste); //Imprime o resulatado no console


                    jLtempatual.setText(teste);

           jTprompt.append(teste);
               Transporte(teste);
                        }

                    });


                }
            }
            catch ( IOException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }            

    }
    }
    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
  String nome="";

  nome=jButton5.getText();
  if(nome.equals("FAN OFF")) {
      jButton5.setText("FAN ON");
        } else {
      jButton5.setText("FAN OFF");

    }                                        

    }

      public static class SerialWriter implements Runnable 
    {
        OutputStream out;

        public SerialWriter ( OutputStream out )
        {
            this.out = out;
        }

        public void run ()
        {
            try
            {                
                int c = 0;
                while ( ( c = System.in.read()) > -1 )
                {
                    this.out.write(c); //Envia 0 pela serial??
                }                
            }
            catch ( IOException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }            
        }
    }
      public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
         EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {  
                        public void run() {
        try
        {

            (new Controle()).connect("/dev/ttyUSB1"); //Passa o nome da porta como parametro para classe connect
                  final Controle frame = new Controle();   
frame.setVisible(true); 
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                        }});
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */



}
```

Comment: Qual é o problema? O que ocorre? Clique em [edit] e adicione mais detalhes à sua pergunta

Comment: A pergunta me parece clara, mas o seu codigo não está. Há vários problemas, especialmente de convenções do JavaBeans. Me parece que você é/era desenvolvedor C#. Em Java, nomes de classes começam com Letras Maiúsculas, nomes de variáveis e métodos com letras minusculas e camelCase. Seu método `Transporte` mais parece nome de classe.
Voltando para seu codigo, não vemos o que está acontecendo com o `initComponents`, pode ser que a Thread de leitura aconteça mais rápida do que a tela é capaz de desenhar os componentes. E no seu `initComponents` ele sobrescreva o que está no seu JLabel

Comment: Oi Gabriel, obrigado por responder. Use o Thread.sleep(1000); na minha thread para dar um tempinho. Qual a sua sugestão?

Comment: Obrigado a todos! Descobri o erro estupido, estava com problemas porque eu chamava o metodo conect antes do jframe. Fiz a correção e agora o codigo funciona como esperado.